# libGL.so and gl.h not available from standard path

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, opengl, mesa

I've just done a fresh install of 11.10, + nvidia-current from xswat ppa (cause the current version shipped with ubuntu is broken for my gpu).

Please take time for understanding each steps. I don't know where to report this issue.

## Installation of nvidia-current[-dev]

After installing nvidia-current and nvidia-current-dev, theses files are missing:

```
/usr/lib/libGL.so
/usr/include/GL/gl.h
```

Both are installed into:

```
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so
/usr/include/nvidia-current/GL/gl.h
```

By default, theses are not accessible though standard path, and broke compilation to many software. (no gl.h found, then no -lGL found.)

## Broken in design solution

To fix that, we need to install libgl1-dev.
libgl1-dev install mesa gl.h in /usr/include/GL/gl.h
and install mesa libGL.so in /usr/lib/libGL.so

With libgl1-dev, i'm able to compile gl related software.
But after compilation, i can see that nvidia libGL is used:

```
$ ldd mysoftware
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f620d78c000)
```

## Conclusion

- we need libgl1-mesa-dev to be able to compile gl-related software by default
- we don't use nvidia header at compilation, but mesa header
- we don't use any mesa lib at runtime

## Questions

- Why should i install Mesa development since i already got everything on my computer ?
- Should ubuntu need to install or symlink nvidia libs and header in standard location if mesa are not installed ?

Comment: This is exactly my problem, but what's under solution is unintelligible.
What does "we need to install libgl1-dev. libgl1-dev install mesa gl.h in /usr/include/GL/gl.h and install mesa libGL.so in /usr/lib/libGL.so" mean? The first line is understandable to me. It should be: "Execute (from the console): sudo apt-get install libgl1-dev.
The second sentence however, I cannot find verb nor subject in. Please restate this so that I can compile an application using openGL.